# Want to add two more conditions in my excel VBA coding

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to add is.. Macro should delete the old from "Master"sheet and refresh the sheet1,sheet2 and sheet3

```
Sub Combine3Sheet()

    Dim Ary As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Ary = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Sheets("Master").Name = "Master"

    For Each Ws In Worksheets(Ary)
        Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy Sheets("Master") _
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Call Formatting

    Next Ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Just corrected the coding formate.. sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this? Delete the data on Master before pasting it?

(Also stop changing the edits on your post)

```
Sub Combine3Sheet()
    Dim Ary As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Ary = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    'Refresh all sources/Tables
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    'Clear All but first Row
    Sheets("Master").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    'Loop sheets
    For Each Ws In Worksheets(Ary)
        Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy
        Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Call Formatting
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok.. i ll take care pf that Thank you! Yes you got it, however want to add the second condintion as well it should refresh the Sheet2, Sheet2,Sheet3 as well

Comment: By refresh you mean to clear them after they are pasted on Master?

Comment: It will work step by step.. first it should refresh the data in sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3.. then it will clear the data from Master sheet and then it will combine the sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3

Comment: Also i want keep first row in master sheet and it should clear the data from column A to specific column

Comment: Sheet1, Sheet2 and sheet 3 are linked internal through excel query so every time when i change the data in main files then i have to manually refresh the table in all the sheets

Comment: I added the `RefreshAll` function, it should work. Edit: Also added clear all but first row.

Comment: Its working fine, however i have to run it twice.. Can you also help me to keep the first row in “Master” sheet  clear the data till specific row and column... please

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo A for this... however i have to run this macro twice for the correct result every time

Comment: That's strange, the last edit i made clears all rows but the first one. It also refreshes the data first. I am definitely confused with no clue as to why you need to run it twice.

Comment: @Rajeshji Please stick to one issue per question, or else you run the risk of being a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-vampire).

Comment: @Ricardo.. Thank you!!! so much for your time and help... its working perfectly fine now..